# Codeigniter 2 restrict controller to command line

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

I need to restrict a controller in CI 2 to only run from command line. The other controllers in the application are accessible from the web.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to check [if is a CLI request:](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();

     if(!$this->input->is_cli_request())
     { 
       // echo 'Not allowed';
       // exit();
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks a lot.